# Ajax Progress Bar always returns 100%

Tags: ajax, progress-bar

Good night people!

I'm trying to make a progress bar using ajax, but unfortunately my percentage always returns 100%

In the browser console it also reports 100% directly without even loading.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{ route('bankSlips.pull') }}",
                data: {
                    selectedBankSlips
                },
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                xhr: function() {
                    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                            var percentComplete = (evt.loaded * 100) / evt.total;
                            
                            console.log(percentComplete);

                            $('.loadingContentModal').html('<b> Uploading -> ' + (Math.round(percentComplete)) + '% </b>');
                        }
                    }, false);

                    return xhr;
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    var count = 0;
                    $(data).each(function(e) {
                        count++;

                        $("#pullBankSlips #bankSlipsContent").append(
                            '<input type="hidden" name="bankSlips[]" value="' + data[e]['bank_slip']
                            .id +
                            '"><div class="row mb-3"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Cliente:</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input readonly value="' +
                            data[e]['client'].name +
                            '" type="text" class="form-control"></div></div><div class="row mb-3"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">E-mail:</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input value="' +
                            data[e]['financial_email_client'].value +
                            '" type="email" class="form-control" name="emailClients[]"></div></div><div class="row mb-3"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Boleto:</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input readonly value="' +
                            data[e]['bank_slip'].original_name +
                            '" type="text" class="form-control"></div><div class="d-flex mt-1 justify-content-end"><a href="{{ env('APP_URL') }}/storage/' +
                            data[e]['bank_slip'].file_path +
                            '" target="_blank">Visualizar Boleto</a></div></div>');

                        if (count != data.length) {
                            $("#pullBankSlips #bankSlipsContent").append("<hr/>");
                        }
                    });

                    $(".loadingContentModal").addClass('d-none');
                    $("#pullBankSlips .modal-header, .modal-body, .modal-footer").removeClass('d-none');
                }
            });
```

I tried switching to the upload progress function